# Multiple RewriteEngine calls, or another way to solve this problem?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have Wordpress multisite installed at the root of my site (the Wordpress files are actually in /wp, but it's configured so that each subsite URL is at the root - eg. /site1, /site2 etc.) This means that there's a Wordpress section in my .htaccess file that I probably shouldn't be touching, because Wordpress might overwrite those changes.

However! There is a redirect I would like to build, from (say) /path/to/oldsite to :8080/newsite, and I don't know how to do this without RewriteEngine. Other redirects I have managed to do basic 301s with, but I don't know how to redirect to a different port that way. My test attempt to have multiple sections that use RewriteEngine didn't work since apparently only the final RewriteEngine section gets heeded?

Anyway, that's my issue. Any suggestions for the best way of building this redirect? Am I just going to have to create empty directory /path/to/oldsite to put a redirect in?

Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no problem with having a second block of `RewriteEngine on` and following rules/conditions. You should not modify anything _inside_ the WP comments in the .htaccess, because WP might overwrite that part, when you flush your permalink settings - but adding your own rewriting before that, works perfectly fine.

Comment: Huh, I must have been doing something wrong earlier, since I tried again and it worked. Thanks.